# Unexpected opacity behaviour in iBooks when using webkit keyframe animations

Tags: css, webkit, ibooks, css-animations

I'm working on an animated illustration for an iBooks epub. Here's a simplified version of the XHTML.

```
<div id="parent">
    <img src="image-1.png" />
    <img src="image-2.png" />
    <img src="image-3.png" />
</div>
```

The character I am animating is a ghost and so I have applied opacity (0.7) to the container div. Spooky.

```
#parent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 178px;
    left: 335px;
    width: 589px;
    height: 1295px;
    z-index: 3;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

In Safari, Chrome and iBooks, I initially got the desired effect, which is that the container causes everything to appear semi-transparent as a whole. (As if you have turned down the opacity on a group of layers in photoshop.)

However, when I apply a webkit keyframe animation to any child element, *in iBooks only*, the behaviour of the opacity changes so that all children become semi-transparent. (As if you have turned down the opacity of each layer within a group in photoshop.)

This means that you can see where the images overlap, which is not the effect I am hoping for.

Why am I getting these two different results?